# There is a way to get a value from views.py into nodels.py?(Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm making a little Django project of money management, I'm using a table layout, inside the tables there are many transactions. I have two SQL tables: "Table" and "Transactions" and I need that when I open the link of one specific table, I need to get just the items which were created in the table page.

Example:

1. I open 'table1' and inside it I create 'value1', 'value2','value4'
2. after, I open 'table2' and inside it I create 'value3' and 'value5'
3. after that, when I open the 'table1' page I need to show
   'value1','value2' and 'value4'
4. and when I open 'table2', I need 'value3' and 'value5'

I wonder if there is a way to take the id of the table I'm inside in the moment and write it into the transactions form to make some kind of 'id', so I can filter the values by it id

Here are my files:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
import tables1.views as vw

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name = 'admin'),
    path('mytables/', vw.mytables, name = 'mytables'),
    path('',vw.home),
    path('table/<int:pk>',vw.table, name = 'tableurl'),
    path('newtable/',vw.newtable,name = 'newtable')
]
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Table
from .forms import TableForm

def home(request):
    now = {}

    return render(request,'tables1/home.html',now)

def mytables(request):
    data = {}
    data['tables'] = Table.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'tables1/mytables.html', data)


def table(request,pk):
    form = TableForm(request.POST or None)
    data = Table.objects.get(idd = pk)
    print(data)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('mytables')
    return render(request,'tables1/table.html',{'data':data, 'form':form}),pk

def newtable(request):
    form = TableForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('mytables')
    return render(request,'tables1/newtable.html',{'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
from .views import table

class Table(models.Model):

    idd = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default= None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tables'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Transacao(models.Model):

    mod = models
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    obs = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Transacoes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.desc
```

**forms.py**

````
from .models import Table
from .models import Transacao

class TableForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Table
        fields = ['name']

class TransacaoForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Transacao
        fields = ['desc','date','value','obs'] ```
````

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, you want a relation between Table and Transaction, where each Table contains (possibly 0 or more) transactions. This is a many-to-one relation that can be done by a Foreign Key. [Read more.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

I modified your code and added the foreign key to it. By adding the foreign key field name to the form you can set the table for each transaction when you create it. And when you need to get the transactions for a table you can do `table.transacoes`. The name transacoes is defined in the related-name attribute of the foreign key.

**models.py**

```
from .views import table

class Table(models.Model):

    idd = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default= None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tables'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Transacao(models.Model):

    # Forein key defined here
    table = models.FogeinKey(Table, related_name='transacoes')
    
    # Also I don't know what this is, you probably don't need it
    mod = models

    date = models.DateTimeField()
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    obs = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Transacoes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.desc
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Table
from .models import Transacao

class TableForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Table
        fields = ['name']

class TransacaoForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Transacao
        # table added here
        fields = ['desc', 'date', 'value', 'obs', 'table']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i already tested with the ForeignKey method, but what i need isn't a form field where you select the table, i need something that automatically recognize the table and "auto add" this information to data, there is a way to do that?

Comment: Somehow you need to specify which table to use unless you have only 1 table. You can pass the table id in the URL. For example, you can have a button in the table view 'Add Transaction' and when you click on it it goes to create transaction view with the table id passed as argument in the URL. you can also use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/) to add transactions in the table view.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve my problem by instead of saving the form data automatically in database with "form.save()", i """manually""" got the data from form using form.cleaned_data for each one of the form fields and saved that data into database using Transaction.objects.create() so that i could save the pk variable into the transactions table with the name of "tableid", that way, the app could link the primary key of each table page and link it to the transactions registered inside that page.